# What is this small Nintendo-branded stand for?

Tags: gaming-accessories, hardware-identification

I found this thing when sorting through some stuff, not sure what it's for but it has Nintendo branding.

[image: Small transparent plastic stand]

Does anybody recognise it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The RVL-016 is a little stand for the Wii-Wii U sensor bar.

This is what it looks mounted while the sensor bar is upside down:

[image]

Comment: Oh we just always used blu-tack to hold ours.